# Glossaries Package not working with amsmath

Tags: amsmath, glossaries

I have a custom document class that my university has provided for thesis writing. Everything compiles just fine until I add in the glossaries package.

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \dfrac already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.214 \newcommand{\dfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{}0}
```

Is the result with

```
amsmath.sty
214
LaTeX Error: Command \dfrac already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.214 \newcommand{\dfrac}{\genfrac{}{}{}0}

etoolbox.sty

Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\end' failed! '\AfterEndEnvironment' will not work.
```

as an error. I can't find a solution anywhere wondering if there is a fix?

Comment: you have defined `\dfrac` twice `amsmath` defines it and presumably something else that you are loading, you mention `glossaries` in your title but in what way is that involved. With no source code shown and only a fragment of the log, it will be very hard for anyone to help.

Comment: please make a small self contained file that shows the problem, start from a copy of your real document and delete everything you can delete while still showing the error then add that test case your your question in a code block.

Comment: also your tex system seems quite old (texlive 2017 at the newest) Perhaps you could consider updating to texlive 2020 or a current miktex.